# What is the best way to detect if an `observableArray` is not set yet or really empty in Knockout?

Tags: javascript, arrays, knockout.js

I want to tell whether an `observableArray` is not set yet or is really empty. For instance, I defined `var arr = ko.observableArray()` and later inject values into `arr` using `ko.mapping(data, mappingConfig, arr)`. I want to know if `arr` is mapped already or not.

However, `var arr = ko.observableArray()` will make `arr()` evaluate to `[]`, rather than `undefined`. (Contrarily, `var val = ko.observable()` will make `val()` evaluate to `undefined`.) I shouldn't judge by the length of `arr`.

I should not use `var arr = undefined` because this will make other computed observables that depend on `arr` unable to get notified after `arr` is mapped. And you cannot `subscribe` to `arr` before it's mapped.

I should not use `var arr = ko.observable()` because it will always be `observable` rather than `observableArray` even if you mapped it from an `array`.

So seemingly I can only keep a flag to indicate whether the `observableArray` is set, e.g. `var arr = ko.observableArray(); arr.isSet = ko.observable(false);`?

---

[Github Issue](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/1921#issuecomment-153435336)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign undefined to an observable array. Thus your initialization would look like this:

```
var arr = ko.observableArray();
arr(undefined);
```

You could even create your own wrapper to do this:

```
ko.undefinedObservableArray = function () {
    var arr = ko.observableArray();
    arr(undefined);
    return arr;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably working against the grain a bit if you're trying to use an observable array that way.

Having said that, keeping a separate flag would work.  To neaten it up a bit you can also create "sub observables" if you wanted to have the flag nicely contained.  Something like

```
var arr = ko.observableArray();
arr.initialised = ko.observable();
```

Then you can observe `arr.initialised` just like any other observable, and passing `arr` around passes its flag too.

Alternatively, why not use `ko.observable()`?  You can still have arrays in there.  Convenience methods like `.push()` aren't tacked on the end for you but that may not matter.  If you do need to mutate the array after putting it into the observable you'll need to do this

```
var arr = ko.observable();
...
arr( [1, 2, 3] );
...
var underlyingArray = arr();
underlyingArray.push(4);
arr.valueHasMutated();
```

Sometimes this can be more performant if you're follow more of a functional style where you have a new array anyway, or if you've got lots of elements to push since the observable will only notify subscribers once rather than on each `.push()` call

Comment: What do you mean by "working against the grain a bit"? Why is it inappropriate to use `observableArray` in my way? your 2nd code block is cool. Is `observableArray.push` so simple behind the scene? I just realized I can manually bind `.push` to `observable` that I know it will be mapped as an `observableArray`.

Comment: I prefer to use `observable` because the code will be more consistent. But I have to attach functions of `observableArray` to the `observable`.